# See webcolors and custom colors in Delphi's Object Inspector colorpicker at design-time

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

when designing a form and its components at design-time, some properties of `color` type allow us to choose colors from a list of predefined default Delphi colors:

[image]

double clicking on this property, we can even see a color-picker which lists some additional options and offers the ability to define custom colors.

However, I would like to define a custom palette for my application; that is, to add some of the named `clWeb` colors to the dropdown list (screenshotted above), maybe even colors that I can name myself.

In short, I would like to make a consistent set of web-colors of my choice to always appear in the dropdown color list when picking colors at design-time in the IDE, so I can color my components in a modern, yet coherent manner.

Themes, while very uniform, are too rigid and introduce weird glitches in places.

Any suggestions?

Delphi 11.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware about any "ready to use" solution. Anyhow, you could try to create your own property editor and register it in the IDE as the editor for the `TColor` type.

It could be a little bit complex, but it basically consists in two parts as mentioned before:

1. Creating the property editor (it should be a [`TPropertyEditor`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/DesignEditors.TPropertyEditor) descendant class)
2. Registering your property editor as as the editor for the `TColor` type (you will need to use the [`RegisterPropertyEditor`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/DesignIntf.RegisterPropertyEditor) procedure)

I also suggest you to read these pages:

- [Adding Property Editors](https://www.delphipower.xyz/components/adding_property_editors.html)
- [How to implement the own custom property editor for all instances of a certain type](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/delphi-how-to-implement-the-own-custom-property-editor-for-all-instances-of-a-certain-type/)
- [Custom colors in Delphi 7](https://groups.google.com/g/borland.public.delphi.vcl.components.writing.general/c/QOqRnS2S1IQ#885b7b40e19b6012)